# Hardware Error 0 then proper number, long boot

Tags: linux, grub2

I debugged my grub and found out that it takes 3 minutes before it starts to lead the kernel, it hangs on last line in this image:
[image]

next what it does is:
[image]

any ideas why ?

Comment: is grub installed on the same physical device as the linux you're trying to load?

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes it is